# Rewire a private function p0, but says: p0 not defined

Tags: node.js, rewire

The main.js is like this

```
const p0 = (a, b) => (a+b)
const p1 = (a, b) => {
    return p0(a, b) + 10;
}
module.exports = { p1 }
```

The test code

```
const rewire = require('rewire');
const myMod = rewire('main');
    it('.test p0', async() => {
        const mockP0 = (a, b) => (a*b);

        myMod.__set__(p0, mockP0);
        return p1(2, 10);
    });
```

ReferenceError: p0 is not defined

I thought rewire can access private functions, how to solve this pls ? Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument should be string or object.

Try

```
myMod.__set__('p0', mockP0);
```

or

```
myMod.__set__({p0: mockP0});
```

Comment: Now it says TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Comment: Because there is not a magic here, it can't reassign const, change it into `let` or standalone `function`

Comment: well, changing to let works. But that defect the propose, i'm changing main code just for the test :(